# Tor usage in North Korea as a foreigner

Tags: tails

I'd like to ask your opinion on whether it's a good idea or not to use the TAILS operating system (which comes with Tor buit in) while on my trip as a tourist to North Korea. The tour organizer says it's possible to access the Internet in North Korea if you buy a SIM card which is sold only to foreigners.

I intend to bring my own laptop and a USB stick from which i will boot the TAILS OS. I absolutely do not intend to perform any activities deemed as illegal or defamatory by the North Korean authorities. I just want to use TAILS + Tor for extra anonymity while browsing the Internet.

Do you think it's risky and it would seem suspicious if my USB stick is inspected and they find out TAILS on it? Do you know of any cases where foreigners successfully accessed Tor from North Korea and would you recommend its usage while in that country?

Comment: I was wondering whether it's possible to LUKS-encrypt the tails partition also (requiring a pass phrase at the (innocent looking) boot manager prompt). Then all they could see is an encrypted partition. And you could say you don't remember the password if asked for...

Comment: This was your last post. Everything go okay did u get in trouble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is too risky.

> I absolutely do not intend to perform any activities deemed as illegal
>   or defamatory by the North Korean authorities.

Using Tor at all may be deemed illegal. You can imagine that if you use the internet, every single packet will be scrutinized and they **can** see that you are using Tor even if they can't see what you are doing. Why take that kind of risk?